# Javascript change div content upon a click

Tags: javascript, onclick, swap, html

I'm pulling a content from PHP array and I have a situation like this:

```
 <div class="weight-display">
 <span>04/25/2011</span> <span>100lbs</span> <span>Edit</span> <a href="http://foo.com">Delete</span>
 </div>
 <div class="weight-display">
 <span>04/27/2011</span> <span>150lbs</span> <span>Edit</span> <a href="http://foo.com">Delete</span>
 </div>
 etc...
```

Now when somebody clicks on Edit within, let's say, first div where weight is 100lbs, I just need that "div" to change and to have input field instead of simple text where weight is (while others will remain the same) and to be like this:

```
<div class="weight-display">
<span>04/25/2011</span> <input type="text" value="100" /> <span>Save</span> <span>Cancel</span>
</div>
<div class="weight-display">
<span>04/27/2011</span> <span>150lbs</span> <span>Edit</span> <a href="http://foo.com">Delete</span>
</div>
etc..
```

So basically div has to "reload itself" and change content. Now I really need some very simple Javascript solution. Preferably I would like a solution with a hidden div beneath original one, so they just swap places when user clicks on EDIT and in a case if CANCEL is pressed to swap places again so original div with text is displayed...

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* Normal mode */
    .weight-display div.edit {display:none}
    /* Editor mode */
    .weight-edit div.show {display:none}
</style>
<div class="weight-display">
    <button onclick="toggle(this)">Edit this!</button>
    <div class="edit"><input type="text" value="Test" /></div>
    <div class="show">Test</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(button)
    {
        // Change the button caption
        button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML=='Edit this!' ? 'Cancel' : 'Edit this!';
        // Change the parent div's CSS class
        var div = button.parentNode;
        div.className = div.className=='weight-display' ? 'weight-edit' : 'weight-display';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Creadiff, this stuff isn't swiching divs, so I guess it's something to do with the code, but I think this is what I need :) can you please check why isn't this working ?

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is basically correct.  I would generate two div's one for display and one edit.  The edit div will initially have `display: none`.  When the Edit is clicked, hide the display div and show the edit div.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

onClick event calls a function (**EDITED to be a little smarter** than my original brute force method):

```
function swapdivs ( id_of_topdiv, id_of_bottomdiv ) {
  var topdiv    = getRefToDiv( id_of_topdiv );
  var bottomdiv = getRefToDiv( id_of_bottomdiv );

  var temp  = topdiv.style.zIndex;
  topdiv    = bottomdiv.style.zIndex;
  bottomdiv = temp.style.zIndex;
}
```

Could that or similar work for you? Or am I missing some subtle yet crucial requirement?

Comment: Pete I will have a huge list and adding ID's can be difficult... I'm really looking for something as simple as onclick for class...

Comment: @Peter -- very interesting you should say this. I just was researching the very same question, although at first glance it seems unrelated, and I believe the answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime/5891638#5891638" . Have a look and see what you think.