# javascript to update div with user input

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript change div content upon a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862489/javascript-change-div-content-upon-a-click)

What I'm trying to do is have this code update the original Test

```
<div class="show">
```

with what the user has put there.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Normal mode */
    .weight-display div.edit {display:none}
    /* Editor mode */
    .weight-edit div.show {display:none}
</style>
<div class="weight-display">
    <button onclick="toggle(this)">Edit this!</button>
    <div class="edit"><select name="Category">
<option value="Department">Department</option>
<option value="Accounts">Accounts</option><option value="Claims">HR</option><option value="Yachts UW">IT</option><option value="Marine Trade">Marketing</option></select></div>
    <div class="show">Test</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(button)
    {
        // Change the button caption
        button.innerHTML = button.innerHTML=='Edit this!' ? 'Save' : 'Edit this!';
        // Change the parent div's CSS class
        var div = button.parentNode;
        div.className = div.className=='weight-display' ? 'weight-edit' : 'weight-display';
    }
</script>
```

original: [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862489/javascript-change-div-content-upon-a-click)

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/f9mBm/

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing ?

Comment: Is there andy difference to your previous question? If not, please don't ask a question twice but clarify your original one. Apart form that, this  current question does not contain enough information to understand your problem.

Comment: When i try this it doesn't update the text
http://jsfiddle.net/f9mBm/

Comment: Hi Felix,
I've never asked this question before.
My requirements are different to the question that I linked to in my question then you posted as a possible duplicate.

Comment: It seems to work fine in chrome. Which browser are you using?
http://jsfiddle.net/f9mBm/1/

Comment: Hi,
I'm using firefox 10.0
Maybe I've explained myself poorly sorry.
http://jsfiddle.net/f9mBm/2/
Does this work for you? When I click Save it still displays the original value in the div "Show".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if I understand you correctly you want to get the selected value from the dropdown and set that value to the div.show ?

In that case you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/f9mBm/3/

Comment: Thank you!
Sorry for explaining this so poorly everyone.