# Class CSS property return

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

How would one return a class computed CSS property/property array?

Like, if I have a class defined in CSS:

```
.global {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px black;
}
```

It's applied on the go with javascript to an `element`. Now I want to change this `elements` *childrens'* `color` to *parents'* (`.global`) element `background-color`.

And is there a way to read CSS properties from a previously defined class in a `style` tag or externally included `*.css`?

Something like, `getCSSData([span|.global|div > h1]);` (where the passed variable is a CSS selector, that gets data for exactly matching element) that would return an object with each property in it's own accessible variable?

Something like:

```
cssdata = {
    selector : '.global',
    properties : {
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        color : 'white',
        textShadow : '0px 1px 1px black'
        // plus inherited, default ones (the ones specified by W3..)
    }
}
```

And the usage for my previously explained example would be:

```
// just an example to include both, jQuery usage and/or native javascript
var elements = $('.global').children() || document.getElementsByClassName('.global')[0].children;
var data = $('.global').getCSSData() || document.getCSSData('.global');
return elements.css('color', data.properties.backgroundColor) || elements.style.backgroundColor = data.properties.backgroundColor;
```

Is there a function built in already in `javascript`/`jquery` and I've overlooked it?

If not, what should I look for to make one?

P.S. Can be DOM Level 3 too.. (HTML5'ish..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the computedStyle of an element which includes all inherited style values, here is a example that outputs the computed style of a div element in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (document.addEventListener) {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", listComputedStyles, false);
    }

    function listComputedStyles() {
        var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        var properties = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);

        for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
        {
            var value = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(properties[i]);             
            console.log(properties[i], value);
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="myDiv" style="background-color: blue; height: 500px;"></div>
```

You can find more information here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljscsoax.php

Answer (score 3):

If you want to grab the background color of the parent element and then apply that color to the font of all of it's children you could use the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

    var global = $('.global');
    var bgColor = global.css('background-color');
    global.children().css('color', bgColor);

};
```

[Here's an example on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/mk99K/)

Comment: That's only one value, as I mentioned in the question, I want to get all the values with a single command. You cannot do it with `*.css();`.

Comment: You want to get all of the values of what?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you'd like to find a general approach to modifying a class; and to have that modifcation affect all of the instantiations of that class. This was the subject of another detailed discussion on SO [**over here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime/5891638#5891638).

There turned out to be an extremely interesting and useful treatment of classes that works in almost all browsers, notably excepting IE8 and below.

Comment: Well, actually I wanted to retrieve the class properties, but all of em', the default ones, computed ones etc. So I can later use those.. But looks like the post there contains a useful information, to guide me into the right direction.