# IE unknown runtime error while setting innerhtml

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, loading, innerhtml, runtime-error

I am trying to set style inside head tag dynamically inside a iframe so as to set the class 
on body of the iframe while loading of the iframe itself, say I want to apply the ze_edit
class on the body of iframe like this ::---

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.ze_edit{font-family:Verdana,arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;}
</style>
</head>
<body class = "ze_edit">
</body>
```

Below is the full code of the sample test file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
test = function()
{
 var _style,
 _iframe,
 _doc,
 _head,
 ff,
 fs;

 ff = "georgia,times new roman,times,serif";
 fs = "30pt"
 _doc = document;
    _iframe = _doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
    _iframe.contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
_style = _doc.createElement("style");
_style.type = "text/css";
_style.innerHTML = ".eclass{font-family:"+ff+";font-size:"+fs+"}";
_head = _iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
_head.appendChild(_style);
_iframe.contentWindow.document.body.className = "eclass";
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
This is a just a test
<iframe onload ="test()">
    satyam
    </iframe>
   </body>
   </html>
```

But this script throws error "**Unknown runtime error**" at this line
"***_style.innerHTML = ".eclass{font-family:"+ff+";font-size:"+fs+"}***";
"  in IE .
Any workaround solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

This could be some IE bug/feautre. Do it like in this post:

[How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/730091/269804)