# changing CSS class definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have this class:

```
.MyClass{background:red;}
```

This class applies to several divs. I want to change the color of the background to orange **by changing the color defined in MyClass.**

Now, I know I could do `$('.MyDiv').css('background', 'orange');`

But my question is really this: how do I change the CSS class definition so that MyClass elements now have `background:orange;`? I want to be able to change several CSS color properties from one color to another.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime

Comment: $('.MyDiv').css('background', 'orange'); *IS* changing the definition of the class '.MyDiv'.  Beyond that, no. You can't edit the css file of course.  the $.css() function provides a way of dynamically changing css, but it can be cumbersome with a lot of properties.

Comment: It is possible however you going to need to parse each rule to get to the rule you want to modify [Read More..](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml)

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: I've never used SASS or LESS, but my understanding is, before the page is served, the SASS/LESS code is interpreted/compiled into standard CSS. So, the client will only receive regular CSS, and the SASS/LESS variables will not exist on the client-side.

Comment: `$('.MyDiv').css('background', 'orange');` would change the background of all div with class `.MyDiv`? What else you want to do? Why do you want to modify the CSS Rule?

Comment: @OnResolve: No, it isn't.  It's modifying the `style` attribute of every element that has the class `MyDiv`.  You can easily tell the difference by adding a new element of class `MyDiv` after that operation and noting that its background is not orange.

Comment: @chaos: yes, you got it. I'm looking to change the definition of the CSS, not the HTML elements.

Comment: @chaos fair enough, however, if dom elements needed to be added, why not run the $.css() stuff after that's said and done? It may technically not change the definition but it will take precedence minus any !important flags doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: @OnResolve: I dunno, it's frenchie's issue.  But it's not hard for me to imagine a scenario where simulating CSS changes rapidly becomes an obnoxious exercise and you'd rather just actually change the CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually altering your stylesheet is pretty challenging.  Much more easily, though, you can *switch out* your stylesheet for a different one, which may be sufficient for your purposes.  See [How do I switch my CSS stylesheet using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846980/jquery-change-css-stylesheet).

For actually altering the stylesheet content, [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime) will get you started.

Comment: yes, I know it's pretty difficult... I'm not looking to switch stylesheet.

Comment: ok, thanks. The link is where I found the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to find the rule you want because you have to iterate through the `document.styleSheets[i].cssRules` array. (and compare your class name with the `selectorText` attribute)
So my solution to this problem is to add a new CSS class, remove the old CSS class from the HTML  element and add this class instead of it.

```js
var length = getCssRuleLength();
var newClassName = "css-class-name" + length;

//remove preview css class from html element.
$("#your-html-element").removeClass("css-class-name");
$("#your-html-element").removeClass("css-class-name" + (length-1));

$("#your-html-element").addClass(newClassName);

//insert a css class
insertCssRule("." + newClassName + ' { max-width: 100px; }', length);


function getCssRuleLength() {
 var length = 0;
 if (document.styleSheets[1].cssRules) {
  length = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules.length;
 } else if (document.styleSheets[1].rules) { //ie
  length = document.styleSheets[1].rules.length;
 }
 return length;
}
function insertCssRule(rule, index) {
 if (document.styleSheets[1].cssRules) {
  document.styleSheets[1].insertRule(rule, index);
 } else if (document.styleSheets[1].rules) { //ie
  document.styleSheets[1].addRule(rule, index);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my answer in case anyone stumbles upon this.  Give your elements a new  class name that doesn't already exist, then dynamically add a style segment:

```
var companyColor = 'orange' //define/fetch the varying color here
var style = '<style>.company-background {background-color: ' + companyColor + '; color: white;}</style>';
$('html > head').append($(style));

//give any element that needs this background color the class "company-background"
```

Answer (score 0):

You  have 2 options

1. add a new stylesheet that overrides this `.MyClass`
2. have a second class with the different property, and change the class Name on these elements

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I think a better approach is to switch **MyClass** with something else using JavaScript rather than to change the properties of the class dynamically.

But if you are still keen you can switch CSS stylesheets with jQuery http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/

Answer (score 0):

```
var changeClassProperty = function(sheetName, className, propertyName, newValue, includeDescendents) {
        var ending = '$';
        setValue = '';
        if (includeDescendents === true) {
            ending = '';
        }
        if (typeof(newValue) != 'undefined') {
            setValue = newValue;
        }
        var list = document.styleSheets;
        for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
            var element = list[i];
            if (element['href'] && element['href'].match(new RegExp('jquery\.qtip'))) {
                var cssRules = element.cssRules;
                for (j = 0, len2 = cssRules.length; j < len2; j++) {
                    var rule = cssRules[j];
                    if (rule.selectorText.match(new RegExp(className + ending))) {
                        cssRules[j].style.backgroundColor = setValue;
                        console.log(cssRules[j].style.backgroundColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
changeClassProperty('jquery.qtip', 'tipsy', 'backgroundColor', 'yellow');
```

Answer (score -3):

You'd be much better off adding and removing classes instead of attempting to change them.

For example

```
.red {
    background: red;
}

.orange {
    background: orange;
}

$('#div').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('orange');
});
```