# Is it valid HTML to have two <style> elements inside your HTML <head> tag?

Tags: html, css, styles

Is it valid to have two `<style>` tags inside of an HTML head tag?

For example I am trying to write an HTML page for email clients with no external stylesheets added.  Due to the way our template system works it is much easier for us to have

```
<head>
 <style>
  .someStyle{}
 </style>
 <style>
  .someOtherStyle{}
 </style>
</head>
```

instead of this...

```
<head>
 <style>
  .someStyle{}
  .someOtherStyle{}
 </style>
</head>
```

If option 2 is the only way of doing this I will do that but option 1 for various reasons works better for our framework code.

Comment: what do you mean instead of..?

Comment: @JonTaylor - It says "Is it valid to have two tags instead of an HTML head tag?"

Comment: @Tom think he meant inside of not instead of.  And lol yeah I deleted my other comment :)

Comment: @WesleyMurch, what do you mean by "the question seems random"? I just came here googling for the same thing, and didn't do it randomly. :) There're singleton elements (apart from HEAD or BODY) like TITLE, BASE etc., and the "cascading" in CSS in itself does not imply the multiplicity of the STYLE *element*. In fact, STYLE is disallowed in BODY, and that blatant restriction (disregarded by every browser for a reason) might urge someone to double-check the multiplicity of STYLE in HEAD. Note: the fact that you can use any of them anywhere, has nothing to do with it being valid.

Comment: The ability to have more than one `<style>` element is useful if using `innerHTML` to drop in a bunch of overriding styles using JavaScript - [like this](https://gomakethings.com/two-ways-to-set-an-elements-css-with-vanilla-javascript/). So it's nice that it's permitted.

Answer (score 13):

It's perfectly fine to have multiple style elements in between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags.
You can have as many as you want, together with `<link>` or `<script>` elements.

Comment: does the top style tag has the higher preference?

Comment: @Juke all style tags will be concatenated together and then the standard rules of CSS regarding specificity and cascading apply.

Answer (score 11):

None of the answers have cited any sources, so the OP cannot be sure. (Note that neither the "cascading" part of "CSS" nor the fact that browsers tolerate many `STYLE` elements proves anything; e.g. they tolerate (thank God, BTW!) `STYLE` elements in the `BODY` as well, even though that's considered heresy by the specs, unless the `scoped` attr. is used, which is in turn largely unsupported by browsers, despite being valid...)

Here's what [the current HTML spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/semantics.html#the-style-element) says today (2017-02-08):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> - If the scoped attribute is absent: where metadata content is expected.
> - If the scoped attribute is absent: in a noscript element that is a child of a head element.
> - If the scoped attribute is present: where flow content is expected, but before any other flow content other than other style
>     elements and inter-element whitespace.

Which effectively means the answer to the original question is, indeed: **yes**. :)

Comment: Ehh-hehh, Google dropped me here, read this answer, and wanted to quickly flick an upvote for adding a source... But it failed... WTF, I read the error msg., which said: "You can't vote for your own post."... No shittin, I realized only then that this nice guy with the link was actually me ~2 years ago!... :-D

Comment: Yeah, the web isn't all that big when you live in specific regions of it. I've come across my own past posts when searching too. Actually, since my memory is poor, I often post questions and answers for my future self, anticipating that I will forget how to do something. Nothing worse than having to re-trace steps through a problem you've already cracked before because you didn't document the solution.  :-p

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is perfectly valid. CSS stands for "cascading style sheets" (as in, layered on top of each other.) Multiple `<style>` tags allow you to include multiple style sheets or multiple style declarations.