# Editing specific inline <style> 's via javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have:

```
<style id=inlinestyle>
    .container {
        height: 0;
    }
    .container li {
        height: 10px;
    }
    .container li a {
                 color: pink;
    }
</style>
```

I would like to be able to target and edit `.container li a' without losing the other styles i have.

```
 $('#inlinestyle').html('#poop { color: red }');
```

This won't work as i will lose everything in there.

Worth mentioning that i'll have an infinity amount of elements being created so inline styles aren't an option.

Comment: Try a string search/replace instead of overwriting the whole thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting CSS pseudo-class rules from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311052/setting-css-pseudo-class-rules-from-javascript)

Comment: i'd argue its not a duplicate as i'm trying to edit the style and not overwrit any of the other.

Comment: A solution to this is also provided in that question (the second line in each code example of the accepted answer), but if you want to have it more explicit: [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be more or less what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ZH9JW/2/

The problem with this is that it's a very rigid regular expression; one space more or less, or no newline characters and the regular expression will fail. You can solve this ofcourse, but then you're starting to build a CSS parser. I recommend against using my solution.

Maybe this is something you could use? It's probably faster than `$("#poop").css("color", "red");` if you're creating so many elements, but a bit of a hack:

```
var newStyle = $("<style/>").html(".container li a { color: red }");
$("body").append(newStyle);
```

This `style` element should by the way ideally be in the DOM after your original `style` element, or have more specific CSS.

Answer (score 7):

wouldn't it just be better to target the element you want to modify ?

```
$('#poop').css('color','red');
```

And if you'd like to add more than one property to the css of that precise element just do:

```
$('#poop').css({
    'color' : 'red',
    'font-size' : '16px',
    ......
});
```

Comment: ye, but i don't want to do this as i'll  have around 100 elements being created on the fly.

Comment: Then why don't you just add it to the css from the start ?

Comment: And? The only benefit of inline styles over programmatically setting styles via JS is that the browser reads the style *first* and then applies it automatically as it renders the page. Once your JS replaces the style definition, you've already lost that advantage. There's essentially no difference at that point. If you're truly worried about efficiency. You should simply define the styles you need to change as a class, and then give every added element that class, instead of setting the style itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#inlinestyle').append('.container li a { /* css here */}');
```

Comment: won't work as i'll just be overwritting and leaving the old styles in there.

Comment: won't work as i'll just be overwritting and leaving the old styles in there. 

This `.abc { color: blue; font-size: 13px }` is the same that `.abc { color: blue } .abc { font-size: 13px }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container li a').css("color", "blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$('#inlinestyle').append(' #poop { color: red; }');` or `$('#poop').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: append isn't an option and inline styles aren't an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inlinestyle').append('#poop { color: red }');
```

Comment: i want to overwrite the styles for that style and only that style.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit your original CSS via JS, but add the desired rules the element which is to get styled:

```
/* What about: */
$( '.container li a' ).css( 'property', 'value' );
/* or */
$( '.container li a' ).css( {
    'property1': 'value1',
    'property2': 'value2'
} );
```

Comment: @Jamie Hutber Is there any reason for not using inline styles in that case?