# How can I get CSS codes in a style element?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML5 Document</title>
<style>
    body {
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

How can I get CSS codes in the `style` element via JS? Thank you.

Comment: What do you need to get? Is it a style of an DOM element?

Comment: Have a look here and see if this solution will work for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707565/how-do-you-add-css-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.innerHTML = "body { \n\
        background: red; \n\
    }";

document.body.appendChild(styleElement);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zjrJ2/

Comment: I wanna GET the CSS codes in a style element. Not SET it. Not get a style element. Is there solution?

Comment: `document.styleSheets[0].innerHTML`