# using javascript to access position/font-color/font-size in a CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, google-closure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime)

lets say i have a CSS class in a file called `storage.css`

`.my-classname {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}`

how do i use javascript to dynamically retrieve and change values of this class?

in `domController.js`

say:

```
var myCssClass = getCssClass(my-classname);
var position = myCssClass.(my-classname.position);
var top = myCssClass.(my-classname.top);

function setCssPosition(newPosition){
   myCssClass.position = newPosition;
}

function setCssTop(newTop){
   myCssClass.top = newTop;
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime

Comment: thanks! @Shmiddty should i close this question then?

Comment: I've flagged it as a duplicate. The mods should take care of it.