# Trying to use querySelectorAll to iteratively run through all items of a particular class and make changes based on a set of conditions

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am trying to make the various sentences in a document, with the class "line", grow increasingly opaque.  When they get to be totally opaque, I want a sound to play and the opacity to begin reducing.  For now I am trying to simply set the opacity to -.5 .

```
    function increaseOpacity() {

      var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");
      var increment = .01;

      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ) {
        var element = lines[i];

        var x = element.getAttribute("opacity");

            if (x <= 1) {
                x += increment;
            }

            else if (x >= 1) {
                x = -.5;
                var audio = new Audio('sound/hush002.mp3');
                audio.play();               
            }

        }
    }


setInterval(increaseOpacity, 500);
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting the attribute, but never setting the attribute.

Comment: Do you have an `opacity` attribute? That's generally a style?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7c3enu2h/

Comment: As a side note, this can be accomplished with CSS transitions as well. You could add a fade-in class and then when the transition ends, add a fade-out class.

Comment: Consider changing the CSS rule instead. It's very much more efficient and doesn't require finding any elements with the class. See [*How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime).

Comment: @adeneo Thanks!  I was able to adapt your jsfiddle and get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Just changing `x` doesn't change the attribute. You have to call the [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method:

```
function increaseOpacity() {

  var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");
  var increment = .01;

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ) {
    var element = lines[i];

    var x = element.getAttribute("opacity");

        if (x <= 1) {
            element.getAttribute("opacity", x + increment);
        }

        else if (x >= 1) {
            element.getAttribute("opacity", -.5);
            var audio = new Audio('sound/hush002.mp3');
            audio.play();               
        }

    }
}

setInterval(increaseOpacity, 500);
```

If you meant to change a style instead of an attribute, do this:

```
function increaseOpacity() {

  var lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");
  var increment = .01;

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++ ) {
    var element = lines[i];

    var x = parseInt(element.style.opacity);

        if (x <= 1) {
            element.style.opacity += increment;
        }

        else if (x >= 1) {
            element.style.opacity = -.5;
            var audio = new Audio('sound/hush002.mp3');
            audio.play();               
        }

    }
}

setInterval(increaseOpacity, 500);
```

Comment: And that will only work if you have a third party script that knows what to do with an `opacity` attribute on an element, as @adeneo suggests in his comment on the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, the OP probably meant to change a style instead of an attribute.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get this to work, but @adeneo's jsfiddle link seemed to do the trick.  Thank you so much for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Opacity is normally a style, not an attribute.

You should use:

```
var x = element.style.opacity;
```

add set it at some point using:

```
element.style.opacity = x;
```

after you increment (or decrement) `x`.