# Modify previously defined style in JS

Tags: javascript, css

A function for creating style constructed as follows

```
function createStyle(css) {
  var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  if(style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(css);
    style.append(textNode);
  }
  head.append(style);
}
```

inspired by [Christoph and TomFuertes code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524721/9475509). Then it is called to create a style with class name `tab`

```
createStyle(`
  .tab button {
    background: inherit;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 6px;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`);
```

and a HTML element using the style

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "tab";
parent.append(div);
```

is also created. So it all works.

After that I need to modify the style with class name `tab`, where following code

```
var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
var css = style[0].innerHTML
var className = css.split(" ")[0].split(".")[1];
```

is used to get the style class name. I have managed to get the style class name `tab` and also the string containing the object in `css`.

The question is how I modify the style without I modify the string and recreate the style? Or if I have to do that, how I should delete the previous defined style if there are already some styles which I have not recorded the order for accessing them through array `sytle[]`.

**Proposed solution**

Using [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime) suggested by [Achu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8187574/achu) I made this function

```
// Change style attribute with value
function changeStyleAttribute(style, attr, value) {
  var N = document.styleSheets.length;
  var styles = document.styleSheets;
  for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    if(styles[i].rules[0].selectorText == style)
    styles[i].rules[0].style[attr] = value;
  }
}
```

which is called

```
changeStyleAttribute(".tab", "width", "299px");
```

and works. I hope there is another better and simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use document.styleSheets[i].cssRules which is an array you need to parse through to find the one you want, and then rule.style.setProperty('font-size','10px',null);

Refer to this link: [How to change/remove CSS classes definitions at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730048/how-to-change-remove-css-classes-definitions-at-runtime).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your for the link @Achu. And what should I do next? I edit my question and post the solution or I answer my question? The last seems rediculous, doesn't it?


It is clear from https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and not absurd :-).