# Change font size of all the text elements inside body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow the user to change the `font-size` of the entire webpage.

I have set the font-size in rem and I am trying to change the font-size of the root so that it reflects for all the elements.

My markup-

```
<body >

        <div id="test-text">
        ALL TEXT
        </div>
        <p>sample text</p>
        <p>sample text2</p>
        <span>sample text3</span>
        <h1>tst4</h1>
        <label>label</label>
<button id="inc">inc</button>
</body>
```

CODE-

```
$('#inc').click(function(){
    $('body').css('font-size','4rem !important');
})
```

CSS-

```
 p{
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  span{
    font-size: 0.5rem;
  }
```

The code is not reflecting anything. What am I missing here?

Comment: You could, possibly, instead change the css class definition:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891638/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m  Sadly, I cannot use a different stylesheet.

Comment: Consider setting font sizes in `rem` units, rather than `px`. Then all you'd need to do is change the `font-size` of the `html` element and all other font sizes would be relative to that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hi. I tried this but for some reason it is not working. I have updated the question. Can you please tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: Unrelated, but you have an extra `</div>`.

Comment: Note that I said to change the font size of `html`, not `body`. You can also use `px` sizing on `HTML`, since everything will be relative to that (i.e., 2rem will be 32px, 0.5rem will be 8px, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't always recognize `!important`. Remove `!important` and it should work.

[How to apply !important using .css()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655925/how-to-apply-important-using-css)

```js
$('#inc').click(function(){
    $('body').css('font-size','4rem');
})
```

```css
p{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

span{
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-text">
    ALL TEXT
</div>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text2</p>
<span>sample text3</span>
<h1>tst4</h1>
<label>label</label>

<button id="inc">inc</button>
```

Comment: wow. can't believe such small things can sometimes take up hours to understand the bug ! thanks buddy ! :D